# Cannot find any GLU documentation

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, glu

I cannot find in Internet any links to "official" GLU downloads or documentation. The links about GLU on opengl.org are defunct. The only GLU API documentation that I found is on MSDN about windows version of GLU. Is there such page as "official" GLU page and documentation and downloads for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/

GLU documentation is the part of OpenGL 2 documentation. There is [a special section for GLU functions](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/index.html#glu).

Comment: Looks like GLU is not actual anymore.